# Autofac not finding the most greedy constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to use Autofac to find the most greedy constructor in a *referenced* dll.

It's not finding it and only finds the one parameterless constructor.

These are the two ctors:

```
public SimpleAuthenticationController() { .. }

public SimpleAuthenticationController(IAuthenticationCallbackProvider callbackProvider) : this()
```

Now this is how I register the stuff with `autofac`:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SampleMvcAutoAuthenticationCallbackProvider>().As<IAuthenticationCallbackProvider>();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(SimpleAuthenticationController).Assembly);

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

nothing too complex.

But this is the only weird thing I can think of.

1. `typeof(MvcApplication)` is the same project where this code exists in, in `global.asax`
2. `typeof(MvcApplication)` is found in a -seperate- dll, which I manually added via `AddReferences`.

Anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: What happens if you temporarily comment out the parameterless constructor — does it resolve successfully using the other one?

Comment: I'll check. please hold..

Comment: Confirmed, works fine with the parameterless ctor commented out.

Comment: Very weird then. What do you use to find out which constructor it calls? Debug+breakpoint? (sorry for the stupid question, but it is often easy to overlook something simple). If the diagnostic is correct, then I have no idea why it could happen. The assemblies should not matter.

Comment: I've put a break point in BOTH ctors. only the parameterless once is 'stopped' inside.

Comment: Well unless someone can answer that directly, the only option I see is to download Autofac sources, compile them, and step through the https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/MostParametersConstructorSelector.cs

Comment: Prevent having multiple constructors in the first place. [This is an anti-pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: The reason I made the call to have 2 ctors is because by DEFAULT, the MVC framework tries to instantiate a parameterless ctor. So unless the consumer of my nuget library new to use DI/IoC and to wire up the proper parameter for the original (only one) ctor, then they would get a really crap and vague error. As such, I created the parameterless ctor which throws an exception, with a war-and-peace message saying: use IoC and use the other ctor, etc. etc. with web links for help. Yes, it's an anti-pattern. But in this case, it's for documentation :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that my greedy *was* getting called, but if you looked at the greedy-ctor, you'll see that I'm doing `: this()`.

This was a beginner error!

So it was calling the greedy ctor, but before it goes into scope, it has to bubble up to the other parameterless ctor. And I kept thinking it was skipping the greedy and just hitting the parameterless.